# How to refer to cells in a table based off a row value in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatables, reference

So l have a 2 column table, with the first column being size, and the next column being weight. I want to create an input where I get a user to type in the object size, and the next cell just spits out the corresponding weight. Is there anyway to do this in excel?

size       weight

1           12

2           15

3           20

For example given the table above I want a user to just type in '2' for size, and an output cell will spit out '15'.

So far I've tried using structured table references, but they only refer to columns? I don't know how to get it to associate a size with the weight in the cell right beside it.

There isn't a formula I can use either that takes the size of the object and spits out the weight either, because the values come from a numerical solution that the scientific paper I'm looking at doesn't specify.

Comment: Are the data unique? This could easily be done with `vlookup`.

Comment: Yeah they're all unique. vlookup can work? I haven't heard of it before, I'll go check it out thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vlookup` like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,0)
```

User enters the size in D1 and D2 spits out the weight.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try just `LOOKUP()` Function

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **E2**

```
=LOOKUP(E1,A2:B4)
```